# Where does "this" variable refers to in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that `this` variable refers to either the *global object* (window in case of browsers) or the *object that contains it* (in case is used in an object's method), unless it is differently specified (e.g using the bind method).

Now, I have the following example:

```
//define an object
var obj = {
    param: 'Luciano',
    bar: function () {
        console.log('"this" inside method: ' + this);
        return this;
    }
};

var a = obj.bar();
console.log(a);
//
var b = obj.bar;
console.log(b());
```

​
the **output** is:

"this" inside method: [object Object]

Object {param: "Luciano"}

"this" inside method: [object Window]

Window { ... }

I can understand why in case of `var a = obj.bar()` the this variable points to the `obj` object. Could someone explain to me please (*in terms of **execution contexts** and **scope chain***) why in case of `var b = obj.bar` the `this` variable equals to `window` object ? I would expect to be equal to `obj` too.

Comment: That's how JavaScript works if you execute the function without context the context will be window object or undefined if run in strict mode.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is not a duplicate. While it does address similar problem it actually asks why `.` didn't bind context to `bar` function when not used with `()`. The simple answer is "because that's how it is" but it does require at least some explanation.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRZri_CHqnA to understand javascript scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually did with `var b = obj.bar; b();` is "take method `bar` of `obj` and call it directly, without `this` (or with `window` as `this`)" vs `obj.bar()` which means "call method `bar` with `obj` as `this`".

The confusion comes from the fact that `.` is not just simple "give me a value for a key", it also "binds" a context if used together with `()` symbols afterwards. Otherwise it does not.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I haven't realize that in the second case I was actually executing the function without context.